# Bug somewhere in my ruby syntax but I cannot find it

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, cloud9-ide

I am creating a music player that pulls the songs from AWS S3 based on recommendations from the Rcmmndr api. The player is a JavaScript player but uses a ruby back-end to get the songs. Every time I go onto the page that has the player, my servers are aborted and I have to restart them again to get my application to run. Here is my ruby script that runs:

```
songs = Database.check('songs').body #This pulls the list of songs from the database
user_id = Database.check("users/" + session[:user] + "/user_id").body #This pulls the user id

uri = URI.parse "http://api.rcmmndr.com/api_key/#{ENV['rcmmndr_api_key']}/recommend/#{user_id}"
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))

#If there are no recommendations then the player randomly selects a song from the database
if response.body.to_s != "{}"
    song = JSON.parse(response.body).to_a.sample(1)[0][0]
    artist = Database.check("songs/" + song + "/artist").body
    title = Database.check("songs/" + song + "/title").body
else
    song = songs.to_a.sample(1)[0][0]
    artist = Database.check("songs/" + song + "/artist").body
    title = Database.check("songs/" + song + "/title").body
end

#The song's information is stored into JSON that is read by the javascript 
song_to_play = {}
song_to_play[:id] = song
song_to_play[:url] = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/#{song}"
song_to_play[:artist] = artist
song_to_play[:title] = title
song_to_play.to_json
```

My terminal spits out about 600 lines that look like this and many others including the location of gems

```
7fc39e1a9000-7fc39e1ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc39e1ab000-7fc39e1ac000 r--p 00022000 00:2a3 35                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fc39e1ac000-7fc39e1ad000 rw-p 00023000 00:2a3 35                        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-    2.19.so
7fc39e1ad000-7fc39e1ae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffc29d2000-7fffc29f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffc29fe000-7fffc2a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

and ends with this

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
```

Can someone help me find the cause of this? When I deleted that code out of my application it ran with the music player not playing being the only problem. (I am coding on Cloud 9 development environment if that matters)

Comment: The bug isn't in your Ruby syntax, it is somewhere within Ruby itself (or a gem that is built on top of C or C++ code).

Comment: Its hard to tell where it comes from without seeing the rest of the code. Might also be in the native extension of a gem you require. You could try to pin it down by commenting out more and more code until it "works".